# Avoid GSON serialization on non fetched lazy objects

Tags: java, hibernate, gson

I am using GSON to serialize my hibernate entity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ACCOUNT", uniqueConstraints = {
    @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = { "SECONDARY_LOGINID", "COUNTRY_CODE" }, name = "SECONDAY_LOGIN_UNIQUE") })
@NamedQuery(name = "Account.findAll", query = "SELECT a FROM Account a")
@DynamicUpdate
public class Account extends BaseModel implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "accountIdfk", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Address> addresses;

@OneToMany(mappedBy = "accountIdfk", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
private List<Contact> contacts;
}
```

While converting entity to json, GSON is trying to fetch all the unfetched object. Is there a way we can ignore to fetch untouched entities and only serialize the fields which have been fetched?

Comment: Use `@Expose` annotation, to include/exclude given property from serialization/deserialization.

Comment: @Amitkumar but inclusion and exclusion of field will get to know at runtime.